# java collection that has key/value pair, and is ordered according to insert order

Tags: java, collections

I want something where I can insert key/value pairs, and the order is the order that I insert the items in.

I have seen some posts regarding map's, but it seems I have to write my own comparator for them.

I want the first item I insert to be the first stored, and the 2nd be the 2nd item in the collection ,etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using a `LinkedHashMap`, from the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

Answer (score 7):

Why not just create a `class` to contain a key and a value, and then store them in your favourite `List` implementation?

```
class Pair {
    Key k;
    Value v;
}

List<Pair> stuff = new ArrayList<Pair>();

Pair p = new Pair();
...
stuff.add(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you would need to use a list with a name/value object

```
List<NameValuePair> values = new Arraylist<NameValuePair>();
```

and then use the list as you would a normal list

```
class NameValuePair {
   private name;
   private value;

  ... get/set
}
```

Comment: I favor the LinkedHashMap suggestion, but, if you go this route, look at Map.Entry and strongly consider using it instead of defining your own NameValuePair class.

Comment: @user949300: `Map.Entry<K,V>` is an interface, not a class, and I'm not aware of any public JDK classes that implement it. I agree that `NameValuePair` should implement it, though.

Comment: @ruakh Check out AbstractMap.SimpleEntry and AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.

Comment: It is a lot of typing...  :-(

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashMap is the proper type of data struture that you're looking for!
As It extends the HashMap(which allows you to have an element in key/value pair) and maintains a linkedlist(which gives you insertion order) of the entries.

Also check out the following types of maps for more information:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Go to AbstractMap and check these out

HashMap & TreeMap

HashTable-http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html